# I can't install my npm package globally

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, npm-publish

I want to create npm package that can be installed globally. I can publish the package, publish new version, but when I want to install it globally, it is not working.

`yarn global add <package>` outputs:

```
success Installed "pentest-tool-lite@0.0.3" with binaries:
  - pentest-tool-lite
```

`npm install -g <package>` outputs:

```
npm ERR! path /nvm/versions/node/v8.7.0/lib/node_modules/pentest-tool-lite/lib/index
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall chmod
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'nvm/versions/node/v8.7.0/lib/node_modules/pentest-tool-lite/lib/index'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! _logs/2017-12-03T16_00_34_926Z-debug.log
```

debug log:

```
7877 info linkStuff pentest-tool-lite@0.0.3
7878 silly linkStuff pentest-tool-lite@0.0.3 has /Users/juffalow/.nvm/versions/node/v8.7.0/lib/node_modules as its parent node_modules
7879 silly linkStuff pentest-tool-lite@0.0.3 is part of a global install
7880 silly linkStuff pentest-tool-lite@0.0.3 is installed into a global node_modules
7881 silly linkStuff pentest-tool-lite@0.0.3 is installed into the top-level global node_modules
7882 verbose linkBins pentest-tool-lite@0.0.3
7883 verbose linkBins [ { 'pentest-tool-lite': './lib/index' },
7883 verbose linkBins   '/Users/juffalow/.nvm/versions/node/v8.7.0/bin',
7883 verbose linkBins   true ]
7884 verbose linkMans pentest-tool-lite@0.0.3
7885 verbose unlock done using /Users/juffalow/.npm/_locks/staging-fa43d53d0ab27b11.lock for /Users/juffalow/.nvm/versions/node/v8.7.0/lib/node_modules/.staging
7886 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/Users/juffalow/.nvm/versions/node/v8.7.0/lib/node_modules/pentest-tool-lite/lib/index'
7887 verbose cwd /Users/juffalow/NetBeansProjects/pentest-tool-lite
7888 verbose Darwin 16.0.0
7889 verbose argv "/Users/juffalow/.nvm/versions/node/v8.7.0/bin/node" "/Users/juffalow/.nvm/versions/node/v8.7.0/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "pentest-tool-lite"
7890 verbose node v8.7.0
7891 verbose npm  v5.4.2
7892 error path /Users/juffalow/.nvm/versions/node/v8.7.0/lib/node_modules/pentest-tool-lite/lib/index
7893 error code ENOENT
7894 error errno -2
7895 error syscall chmod
7896 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/Users/juffalow/.nvm/versions/node/v8.7.0/lib/node_modules/pentest-tool-lite/lib/index'
7897 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
7898 verbose exit [ -2, true ]
```

Yarn seems to install it successfully, but not. NPM shows error but I really don't know why? Do you have any experience with [module](https://github.com/juffalow/pentest-tool-lite)?

Comment: Can you paste the relevant log from `_logs/2017-12-03T16_00_34_926Z-debug.log`?

Comment: I edited the original post. Thank you!

Comment: Uninstall all the garbage like nvm and yarn. Reinstall node from official website. And install again. It will work then.

Comment: I don't think nvm or yarn is a garbage. The problem should be somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem. When you want to publish global module to npm, you have to publish build version ( e.g. bin or lib folder ). I had this version but ignored in `.gitignore` because it need not to be in repo. And when you don't have `.npmignore` npm uses `.gitignore` file, so the module was published without build version, therefore without executable files.

Solution: add `.npmignore` file to the root of the project with:

```
node_modules/
coverage/
```